# Finding the volume of oil in a cylinder which is lying parallel to the ground.

Tags: volume, solid-geometry

A cylinder of height 2 m  and radius 2 m is partially filled with oil.  When the cylinder is lying parallel to the ground the height of oil level is 1.5 m from ground.  What is the volume of oil? How to solve it?  I didn't find any similar questions.  If this is a duplicate,  kindly give me the link to that post.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you draw a circle of radius $2$ and a horizontal chord at a height of $1.5$ above the bottom of the circle, then this chord is $0.5$ below the centre of the circle. We need to find the area of the segment below the chord and multiply this by the length of the cylinder, $2$.

The area of the segment is $$\frac 12(2)^2(\theta-\sin \theta),$$ where $\theta=2\arccos(\frac{0.5}{2})$ measured in radians.

You should be able to get the answer now.

Comment: David I understood everything except the formula to  find the value of tita.  And what does the tita really mean? Can u please explain the formula of tita?  Thanks.

Comment: $\theta is the obtuse angle subtended by the chord